# Why the copy constructor called, when I return just a reference of the object c++

Tags: c++

It is the code which I cannot figure out why it is not working the way I want, I look around the internet, but did not some good solution.

**Point class:**

```
class Point
{
public:
    Point(const Point &) {
        cout << "copy constructor was called" << endl;
    }
    Point(int x, int y) : x(x), y(y) {
    }
    void setX(int x) {this->x = x;}
    void setY(int y) {this->y = y;}
    int getX() const { return x; }
    int getY() const  { return y; }
private:
    int x;
    int y;
};
```

**Circle class:**

```
class Circle
{
private:
    int rad;
    Point &location;
public:
    Circle(int radius, Point &location) : rad(radius), location(location) {}
    int getRad() { return rad; }
    Point & getLocation() { return location; }
};
```

**The usage:**

```
int main() {
    Point p(23, 23);
    Circle c(12, p);

    Point p1 = c.getLocation();
    p1.setX(200);

    cout << p.getX() << endl; // prints 23, which I want to be 200
                              // copy constructor was called

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Because `p1` is *not* a reference.

Comment: try `Point& p1 = c.getLocation();`

Comment: @WhozCraig hmmmmm.......OK, I am new to C++, and came form Java. Thank You very much!

Comment: For those coming from Java: C++ does not have garbage collection. A reference generally won't keep an object alive. That will be a problem for `class Circle`, as it won't keep the `Point` alive.

Comment: @MSalters can you tell me, how long the Circle class keep the Point alive? I think till the Circle object is not destroyed, the Point can be alive, right? If not, then what the use of a class, we create a class to help us keep the data until the program exist.

Comment: @MSalters I know when the Circle object goes out of scope, it will be destroyed. It is also the same thing in Java, when an object goes out of scope it will become garbage.

Comment: @BahramdunAdil: A class will keep its members alive, but that just means `Circle::location` (the reference) stays alive. It doesn't mean the referened `Point` object itself stays alive. If `Circle::location` would have been a non-reference member, it would be an object itself, and destroyed as part of `Circle`. C++ has strong value semantics. That's why in C++ there is no `Integer/int` distinction like in Java.

Comment: @MSalters Can you give me an example to show when the Point will be destroyed in case of the Circle is still alive? I think that the location member can be get-able and modifiable n times at any time from any place. Right? If not please explain, in what situation the member variable will be destroyed whenever it is a reference member variable or value member variable or pointer member variable?

Comment: @MSalters The location is a global variable of the Circle class not a local variable, so it must be alive till the Circle is alive. If not then what is the meaning of encapsulating and modeling?

Comment: Simple example to fit in comment: `Point *p = new Point(5,5); Circle c(12,*p); delete p; std::cout<<c.location().getX();`. Undefined Behavior. It _might_ print 5, since it's such a simple example, but it's a ticking time bomb. `delete p` has destroyed the `Point` object that `c.location` still references.

Comment: @MSalters hmmmm.. nice, but it has deleted by you, not by the compiler (automatically become garbage and gone). So in your this example I learned that the member variable can be alive as long as the object is alive, except that yourself delete that member object, which is nothing to worry about.

Comment: @MSalters If like this, then it is also possible in Java, `Point p = new Poin(2,2); Circle c = new Circle(12, p); p = null; System.out.println(c.getLoaction().getX()); // oops NullPointException`

Comment: @BahramdunAdil in C++, compiler doesn't delete anything. There is no such thing as garbage collection, so you have to delete any allocated memory. Otherwise you will experience memory leak

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the following line:

```
Point p1 = c.getLocation();
```

`p1` is not a reference, so basically you're copying the referenced object returned by `getLocation()`, thus calling copy constructor.

A solution would be to declare `p1` as a reference like this:

```
Point& p1 = c.getLocation();
```

Comment: Thank You! I am coming from Java which there is no such kind of points to take care of. So in C++ there are lot of things to must be learned well.